# Displaying a patter

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, iteration

The code has to show the following pattern:

```
1

2 2 

3 3 3 

4 4 4 4 

5 5 5 5 5
```

This is my code and its output:

```
for i in range(6):
    # At a glance, Line 14 range(i) starts at 0.
    for x in range(i):
        print(x, end=' ')
    print("\n")
```

**Output of my code**

```
0 

0 1 

0 1 2 

0 1 2 3 

0 1 2 3 4
```

Any help will be really appreciated
Thanks. Happy coding.

Comment: As you see programmers start to count at 0, so does `range()` if not told otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

Because you print `x` not `i` and also because `range()` by default starts from 0

```
for i in range(1,6):
    for x in range(i):
        print(i, end=' ')
    print()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(1,6):
    for j in range(i):
        print(i,end=' ')
    print('\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

so there will be 2 main issues with your code you need to fix the first one is mentioned in a comment above where computers will start counting at 0 so you need to change all of your range statements to

```
range(1,6)
```

rather than

```
range(6)
```

second the problem that you mentioned in your title you can fix by replacing the

```
print(x,end = "")
```

with

```
print(i,end = "")
```

this should print the number you want rather than incrementing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're printing the number that is being iterated in the second loop. So you need to print i not x

```
for i in range(6):
    for x in range(i):
        print(i, end=' ')
    print('\n')
```